# Mapreduce for Displaying all words starting from a-z

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Im trying to get all words starting from alphabet a to z. 
Output of Reduce function should be like: `key="alphabet", value="list of words against alphabet + their count"`

Im using following code but its only display word frequencies but not list of words.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCountFrequency {

    public static class WordCountFrequencyMap extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token=tokenizer.nextToken();
                if (token.startsWith("A")) {
                    word.set("A_Count");
                    output.collect(word, one);
                } else if (token.startsWith("B")) {
                    word.set("B_Count");
                    output.collect(word, one); 
                }
            }//end of while
        }
    }

    public static class WordCountFrequencyReduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCountFrequency.class);
        conf.setJobName("WordCountFrequency");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(WordCountFrequencyMap.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(WordCountFrequencyReduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(WordCountFrequencyReduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

I want to display output like this:

`"Alphabet, 'list of words', word counts"`

```
A: Apple, Ant, And, Add, Axis, 5[wordcount]                                
B: Ball, Bat, Boy, Bus, 4                                                 
....
Z: Zebra, Zinc, Zeal ,3
```

How to display output like mentioned above.

Comment: by "alphabet", you mean "letter"? also, what do you want to count? the number of words for each letter, or the sum of their frequencies?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudocode of the solution

```
map(LongWritable key, Text value) {
    for each token in value:
        output.collect(token.charAt(0), token)
}

reduce (Text letter, Iterable<Text> words) {
    String result = "";
    int count = 0;
    for (Text word : words) {
        result += word.get()+", ";
        count++;
    }
    output.collect(letter, new Text(result+count));
}
```